# How to get all list from two different collection in cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I Have one collection name as **Purchase_Item** and other collection name as **Sale_Item**, I want these two collection full list in one query. Is it possible to get the two list at the same time

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

> I want these two collections full list in one query

No, actually you cannot do that. Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that you can only get documents from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from two top-level collections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go.

If your requirement is to query the database only once in order to get the content of both collections, then you should consider changing your database schema by creating a single collection that holds the items from both collections:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- items (collection)
        |
        --- $itemId (document)
        |     |
        |     --- type: "purchase"
        |     |
        |     --- //Rest of the fields
        |
        --- $itemId (document)
              |
              --- type: "sale"
              |
              --- //Rest of the fields
```

In this way, you can get all items at once. However, if you need to distinguish them, then you should use a Query. For instance, if you only want to get all the items for sale, you can use the following Query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
CollectionReference itemsRef = rootRef.collection("items")
Query qyeryItemsForSale = itemsRef.whereEqualTo("type", "sale")
```